# Write an object into hadoop hdfs issue

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to write an object into hdfs .

```
Split currentsplit = new Split();
Path p = new Path("C45/mysavedobject");
ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fs.create(p));
oos.writeObject(currentsplit);
oos.close();
```

But I am not able to get the exact object value.

```
Path p = new Path("C45/mysavedobject");
Split curntsplit = null;
ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fs.open(p));
try {
    curntsplit = (Split) ois.readObject();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 ois.close();
```

Showing duplicate objects value.

In driver i am getting :

```
objjjjjjj in driver pck.Split@14da173c
```

After writing the object into file and reading back within driver itself I am getting an alternate object value.

```
objjjjjj in mysavedobject pck.Split@62eade0
```

I want the driver object along my Mapper code.

Why is it so?

Comment: Your stacktrace doesn't match the code you have provided.

Comment: Thomas i am including this in between my code.and i am geting this stacktree

Comment: This isn't possible, because you are not using a `FileInputStream` in your provided code.

Comment: ys Thomas . Let me check i think i pasted the previous code:(

Comment: I am really sorry Thomas. Thinking something i posted the qusetion : pls see my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom Split object (pck.Split) doesn't have a toString method defined so what you're seeing is the class name followed by an address in memory (as Java has no otherway to display to you the string value of that object).

Simply add a toString method implementation to your custom Split class and rerun - now you should be able to confirm whether the written and read object has the same contents.

Comment: Thanks Chris White. Now they are the same content :)